# Delete unchanged rows between two dates

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

I inherited a very old and huge (100M rows) table in SQL Server. It's the daily snapshot of accounts and balances but some of those accounts are not even changing anymore but are being added every day (don't ask why!)

I want to:

- Identify and delete unchanged rows unless there is a change
- Create a query that give me the deleted rows when they want it as if they are still there

I have a date dimension table which can be utilized.

This generates the current table:

```
CREATE TABLE #Account_Snapshot(
[Snapshot_Id] [int] NOT NULL,
[Snapshot_Date] [date] NOT NULL,
[Account] [nvarchar](20) NOT NULL,
[Balance] [decimal](18, 2) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_Account_Snapshot_1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Snapshot_Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = 
OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

INSERT INTO #Account_Snapshot VALUES(1, '2019-01-01', '1', 1505.31)
INSERT INTO #Account_Snapshot VALUES(2, '2019-01-01', '2', 2337.48)
INSERT INTO #Account_Snapshot VALUES(3, '2019-01-01', '3', 1088.07)

INSERT INTO #Account_Snapshot VALUES(4, '2019-02-01', '1', 1505.31)
INSERT INTO #Account_Snapshot VALUES(5, '2019-02-01', '2', 2132.17)
INSERT INTO #Account_Snapshot VALUES(6, '2019-02-01', '3', 1088.07)

INSERT INTO #Account_Snapshot VALUES(7, '2019-03-01', '1', 1505.31)
INSERT INTO #Account_Snapshot VALUES(8, '2019-03-01', '2', 2132.17)
INSERT INTO #Account_Snapshot VALUES(9, '2019-03-01', '3', 749.23)

SELECT * FROM #Account_Snapshot
ORDER BY  Account, Snapshot_Date


Snapshot_Id Snapshot_Date Account              Balance
----------- ------------- -------------------- ---------------------
1           2019-01-01    1                    1505.31
4           2019-02-01    1                    1505.31
7           2019-03-01    1                    1505.31
2           2019-01-01    2                    2337.48
5           2019-02-01    2                    2132.17
8           2019-03-01    2                    2132.17
3           2019-01-01    3                    1088.07
6           2019-02-01    3                    1088.07
9           2019-03-01    3                    749.23
```

I need a delete logic that identifies unchanged rows and delete them first:

```
DELETE FROM #Account_Snapshot WHERE Snapshot_Id IN (4,6,7,8)

SELECT * FROM #Account_Snapshot
ORDER BY  Account, Snapshot_Date

Snapshot_Id Snapshot_Date Account              Balance
----------- ------------- -------------------- --------------------
1           2019-01-01    1                    1505.31
2           2019-01-01    2                    2337.48
5           2019-02-01    2                    2132.17
3           2019-01-01    3                    1088.07
9           2019-03-01    3                    749.23
```

Then when the table is way smaller I need to have a query to create a view probably using the date dimension table to be able to produce the results on the fly.

Comment: Is there _always_ a daily entry for every account that existed at the time? Tip: It's helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers. Note that `tsql` narrows the choices, but does not specify the database.

Comment: Thank you for the hint, I tagged the product and version. Yes, there is a daily snapshot of all the accounts even historical ones. I have tried to change this but there are so many dependencies that make it impossible, that's why I am trying to come up with a different approach.

Comment: Possibly LAG function to get previous balance in a sub-query and then you can filter where balance equals previous balance(basically no change).   As part of your other question where you want a view to represent the data the same as before, are you including the Snapshot_id in those results?

Comment: No, that is just table's ID and I really don't care about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an option using [LAG()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) to get the previous balance for an account, use that in a sub-query and then you can filter where balance equals the previous balance(basically no change) to get the records you want to remove:

```
--Show what records to remove
SELECT *
FROM   (
           SELECT *
                , LAG([Balance], 1, 0) OVER ( PARTITION BY [Account]
                                              ORDER BY [Snapshot_Date]
                                            ) AS [PreBalance]
           FROM   [#Account_Snapshot]
       ) AS [p]
WHERE  [p].[Balance] = [p].[PreBalance];

--Then just to delete them
DELETE p
FROM   (
           SELECT *
                , LAG([Balance], 1, 0) OVER ( PARTITION BY [Account]
                                              ORDER BY [Snapshot_Date]
                                            ) AS [PreBalance]
           FROM   [#Account_Snapshot]
       ) AS [p]
WHERE  [p].[Balance] = [p].[PreBalance];
```

After deleting, to represent the data as before, yes you would need a calendar table, from that build out an Account/Date table (combination of all accounts and all dates) and then cross apply back to your original table to fill in the balance.

Example:

```
--Quick sample calendar table
INSERT INTO [#cal] (
                       [CalDate]
                   )
VALUES ('2019-01-01')
     , ('2019-02-01')
     , ('2019-03-01');

--So this would get us a full list of all accounts and dates based on you calendar table
SELECT     *
FROM       [#cal] [a]
INNER JOIN (
               SELECT DISTINCT [Account]
               FROM   [#Account_Snapshot]
           ) [b]
    ON 1 = 1;
```

Results as:

```
CalDate     Account
2019-01-01  1
2019-02-01  1
2019-03-01  1
2019-01-01  2
2019-02-01  2
2019-03-01  2
2019-01-01  3
2019-02-01  3
2019-03-01  3
```

Then use that in a sub-query and cross apply back to the account table to fill in the balance:

```
SELECT      *
FROM        (
                SELECT     *
                FROM       [#cal] [a]
                INNER JOIN (
                               SELECT DISTINCT [Account]
                               FROM   [#Account_Snapshot]
                           ) [b]
                    ON 1 = 1
            ) AS [AcctCal]
CROSS APPLY (
                SELECT   TOP 1 [acct].[Balance]
                FROM     [#Account_Snapshot] [acct]
                WHERE    [acct].[Account] = [AcctCal].[Account]
                         AND [acct].[Snapshot_Date] <= [AcctCal].[CalDate]
                ORDER BY [acct].[Snapshot_Date] desc
            ) AS [bal];
```

Giving you back your original results:

```
CalDate     Account Balance
2019-01-01  1       1505.31
2019-02-01  1       1505.31
2019-03-01  1       1505.31
2019-01-01  2       2337.48
2019-02-01  2       2132.17
2019-03-01  2       2132.17
2019-01-01  3       1088.07
2019-02-01  3       1088.07
2019-03-01  3       749.23
```

Comment: wow! that is fantastic man! thank you very much. I was working on a function for a specific date but this one is the one I was looking for.

Comment: Wanted to make this answer useful it didn't let me.

Answer (score 0):

To identify the rows that had not changes, we can use the row_number with partition in a CTE, as below:

```
;with cte as (
  select *
 ,ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by [Account],[Balance] order by [Account],Snapshot_Date,[Balance]) [Row]
from #Account_Snapshot 
),DataFiltered  as (select * from cte where cte.[Row]=1  --not a duplicate
),DataDuplicate as (select * from cte where cte.[Row]>1  --any number larger than one is a duplicate
)
   select * from DataFiltered
   ORDER BY  Account, Snapshot_Date
```

resulting :-

```
Snapshot_Id Snapshot_Date   Account Balance Row
1           2019-01-01      1       1505.31 1
2           2019-01-01      2       2337.48 1
5           2019-02-01      2       2132.17 1
3           2019-01-01      3       1088.07 1
9           2019-03-01      3       749.23  1
```

to get the duplicate data we can change the last two lines to the below:-

```
select * from DataDuplicate
ORDER BY  Account, Snapshot_Date
```

resulting :-

```
Snapshot_Id Snapshot_Date   Account Balance Row
4           2019-02-01          1   1505.31 2
7           2019-03-01          1   1505.31 3
8           2019-03-01          2   2132.17 2
6           2019-02-01          3   1088.07 2
```

to delete the duplicate data we replace the last two lines with :-

```
delete from #Account_Snapshot where Snapshot_Id in (
select Snapshot_Id  from DataDuplicate)
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: This is very good! thank you. Just tested this on a backup and worked like a charm. Now I need help on a query that can generate the result for one of the dates I deleted.

Comment: Wanted to make this answer useful it didn't let me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
;with cte as (
select *,ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by balance order by Snapshot_Id) rn from #Account_Snapshot
)

Delete from cte where rn > 1
```